# Discord bot not running correctly from EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, discord.py

So I am having an issue with my code where it works on my PC but does not work remotely on AWS! so odd.. this is a discord bot that sends PMs notifying a team when a match has been scheduled... here is the code..

````
        for i in teamRosters[Team1]:
            if(teamRosters[Team1][i][1] == "Captain"):
                user = client.get_user(teamRosters[Team1][i][3])
                await user.send("```Your match with " + Team2 + " will be on " + upcomingMatches[currentMatch][6] + " at " + upcomingMatches[currentMatch][7] + "```")                              
        
        Team2 = str(upcomingMatches[currentMatch][4])
        for i in teamRosters[Team2]:    
            if(teamRosters[Team2][i][1] == "Captain"):
                user = client.get_user(teamRosters[Team2][i][3])
                await user.send("```Your match with " + Team1 + " will be on " + upcomingMatches[currentMatch][6] + " at " + upcomingMatches[currentMatch][7] + "```")
````

now.. on my PC this code executes flawlessly.  However on AWS EC2.. the second user.send says that send is not an attribute of NoneType!  Even tho the first one is ok.. so I do not really understand.. Any ideas? teamRosters[Team2][i][3] stores their discord client ID.  One thing I did try was to make the second 'user' object 'user3' instead

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you mean by AWS?
AWS Lambda?

Comment: apologies! EC2 is what I am using.. t2.micro

Comment: Have you tried to use docker?

Comment: I never heard of docker, im a little inexperienced.. but I am learning that my user = client.get_user(teamRosters[Team2][i][3]) is returning None on EC2 where it is actually working on my PC.  whats docker?

Answer (score 0):

Went with fetch_user instead, works with that.  Thought get_user should also be working so something to figure out.